# CSS linear-gradient: How to set fixed color-stop location counting from bottom

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm looking to create a gradient background for my content area. The gradient would simply be solid white, fading in from zero opacity at the top and again fading back to zero opacity at the bottom. As the content height is highly variable, relative color-stop locations don't fare well.

At the moment I have this CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(
  to bottom, 
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
  rgba(255,255,255,1) 500px,
  rgba(255,255,255,1) 90%,
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%
);
```

I'm looking to replace the `90%` with something that would equal `(content height) - 500px`. Is this possible and how is it done?

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the 500px for?

Comment: if `(content height)` is dynamic, use JQuery.

Comment: @Znaneswar are you serious or it's a simple joke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `calc`:

```css
body {
 min-height:1500px;
 margin:0;
 background: linear-gradient(
  to bottom, 
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
  rgba(255,255,255,1) 500px,
  rgba(255,255,255,1) calc(100% - 500px),
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%
);
}
html {
 background:pink;
}
```

Or consider multiple background where you can adjust `background-size`/`background-position`

```css
body {
  min-height: 1500px;
  margin: 0;
  background: 
  /* Top part will take 500px*/
  linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff) top/100% 500px,
  /*Bottom part will take 500px*/
  linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #fff) bottom/100% 500px,
  /*Middle part will take (100% - 2*500px) */
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/100% calc(100% - 1000px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

html {
  background: pink;
}
```